# Binding language not work

Tags: xml, internationalization, sapui5

I create my .properties file (it, en, fr) and I set the i18n Model

```
    var oI18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
        bundleUrl: "i18n/i18n.properties"
    });
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oI18nModel, "i18n");
    this.setModel(oI18nModel, "i18n");
```

My app start correctly in italian. Now I have a button that switch to en language. This is the code:

```
   var bundleLocale=sap.ui.getCore().getModel("i18n").getProperty("/bundleLocale/");
   bundleLocale="en";
   sap.ui.getCore().getModel("i18n").refresh(true);
```

but the view not change...

Why?

At start the i18n model contains:

```
bundleUrl= "i18n/i18n.properties"
```

After that I execute this code:

```
i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
                bundleUrl    : "i18n/i18n.properties",
                bundleLocale : "fr"
            });
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
```

and the model now contains

```
bundleUrl= "i18n/i18n.properties"
bundleLocale="fr"
```

Instead if I use this code:

```
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().setLanguage("fr")
```

the i18n model not change

in both cases my view not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem!
In my Component.js, in `init` function I had written:

```
    var oI18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
        bundleUrl: "i18n/i18n.properties"
    });
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oI18nModel, "i18n");
    this.setModel(oI18nModel, "i18n");
```

and in `createContent` function I had written:

```
    // create root view
    var oView = sap.ui.view({
        id: "app",
        viewName: "stg.view.App",
        type: "JS",
        viewData: {
            component: this
        }
    });
```

And when I wanted to change the language I had writted:

```
        var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
            bundleUrl    : "i18n/i18n.properties",
            bundleLocale :  sBundleLocale
        });
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(i18nModel , "i18n");
```

but in this mode I had not saw any change.
Now I write

```
var oApp = sap.ui.getCore().byId("app");
oApp.getViewData().component.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
```

It works!!

Comment: I think the real error is because you set the model twice: once to the core `sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oI18nModel, "i18n");` and once to the app `this.setModel(oI18nModel, "i18n");` since the core sits "deeper", setting the model there has no influence if you also set the model explicitly to the app on top of it. Besides, since language settings are considered global, I would just set them to the core anyway, and not to the specific app/views on top

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you're getting a property from your resource bundle (i.e., one of the translations), and not the actual Locale
Furthermore, you are setting a variable `bundleLocale` but you never use that variable...

The correct way of setting the application language is using the `sap.ui.core.Configuration`'s `setLanguage()` method (see https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Configuration.html#setLanguage)

As an alternative, provide the locale with your resource model:

```
setLanguage : function(sLanguage) {
    i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
        bundleUrl    : "i18n/i18n.properties", 
        bundleLocale : sLanguage
    });
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
}
```

EDIT: See this working example http://plnkr.co/edit/pj6Ze1D60lrXQ47peowT?p=preview

Use the switch in the view to toggle between German and English UI language

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing wrong... see my updated answer for a working example

Comment: do you know if there is a possibility to get the users default language? from browser settings or something like that (without any additional service).

Comment: The Javascript way : `navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage` - The SAPUI5 way: `sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getLanguage()`